# Clone a repo from commandLine

Tags: linux, git, tfs

I'm trying to clone a repo from tfs
I open mobax and write : `git clone http://${tfsUsername}:${tfsPasswordEncoded}@your-tfs-url/your-collection/_git/your-repo` and get `authentication failed`
so I tried `git clone http://$@your-tfs-url/your-collection/_git/your-repo` and it asks me for username and password, I entered the exact `${tfsUsername}:${tfsPasswordEncoded}` from the URL and it clone the repo fine

What can be the different?

By the way I tried to run `ssh` command from git with the same results

Comment: If the username or password contains characters that have a special meaning to the shell you might have to quote the URL or the affected part.

Comment: no, just some regular characters

Comment: Are you sure you have to use insecure `http://` instead of `https://`? Maybe you get redirected to HTTPS and the credentials get lost in the process.

Comment: @Bodo Please don't ask people to post their passwords, regardless of whether they change it beforehand.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that I need //

Comment: Bobo let's say my user is user1 and password is pass1